# How to make my signal square without using two MOSFETs (and inverting it twice?)

Tags: mosfet, inverter, non-inverting

I am trying to extend an existing solution to decode a specific signal (solved here for 1200bps speed: http://hallard.me/demystifier-la-teleinfo/ - article in french.)

- A 9600bps signal comes from a 3rd party, buzzing at 50kHz for a 0, not buzzing for a 1
- An optocoupler isolates the circuit, and a N-MOSFET makes squares out of the signal

My problem is that I only know how to make nice beautiful squares with a MOSFET, but doing it this way also inverts the signal.

I came up with a solution that really feels overkill, or at least, not particularily good to me: use two MOSFETs to invert the signal twice. (I could not use the optocoupler as an "inverter" since I only have ground and signal pins for the 3rd party signal.)

Is there a more obvious solution to create a square signal in that situation that's not inverted?

Working schematic, but maybe too complex:

[image: Working Schematic - but maybe too complex]

Yellow signal measured at tags "RX" (the buzzing signal) and blue "RX0" (out of the optocoupler.)
[image: Signal téléinfo+sortie optocoupleur]

Blue signal measured at tags "RX1" (trying to reduce artefacts) and yellow "RX2" (good squares, but inverted.)

[image: Fix some artefacts+mosfet inverted signal]

Background: I am not an electrical engineer, I sometimes make some PCBs. I'm clearly not expert at signal treament.

**Edit**: Thanks for the comments about emitter follower and/or opamps and/or comparator. I guess that would be solutions with maybe an explanation link and/or a schematic.

Comment: Can you connect optocoupler output as high-side (collector to Vcc, emitter as output)? Emitter follower and non-invert OpAmp does not invert the signal, btw.

Comment: A comparator would be an easy solution.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický  (1) Ok I will try to use emitter as output (2) ok will have to RTFM about OpAmps, I guess, that was my most hated part when I was a student ; any suggestion about schematics involving OpAmp | comparator ?

Comment: Emitter follower will reduce the output voltage swing. (May still be adequate)

Comment: @DeanFranks Thanks, I think this is one of the solutions I was looking for. It might seems obvious, but not for newbies.  Qwant point me there: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments suggested using "comparators" (there are some explanations there https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html). Here is the schematics with mosfets replaced with a comparator, and a voltage divider to mark the expected limits of the square:
[image: Schematics teleinfo with comparator]

The result signal is about the same (not inverted), and the BOM is 2€ less expensive :
[image: Output of optocoupler in blue, output of the comparator yellow]

Haven't tested the "emitter/follower" seen in comments, though I don't really see how exactly it would solve the original problem : creating a square signal from that 50kHz buzzing input.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a comparator is the safest solution, as stated in the comments. There are lots of single channel, low-voltage supply (e.g. even lower than 5V) comparators in SOT-23 packages in the market.

For low frequency applications such as RS-232/485 at 19.2k baud or lower, I use the following translator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyyl9v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The advantage of the circuit above is that there's no need for an extra inverter. However, the output capacitance of the optocoupler (i.e. transistor's C-E capacitance) and R1 brings a delay, so a small phase difference between the input and output may occur. I don't think that this will be a problem for your application. Nevertheless, you may need to play with R1 and R2 accordingly for best results. Here's the simulation result of the above circuit (Orange is the input signal and the blue is the output signal):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I attempted with 3 different NPN (but no 2N3906), and the shape SIG_OUT were very similar to the signal "RX" above (but reversed). I guess I can then pipe the signal to the mosfet for a square.

Comment: @JB. 3906 is PNP.

Comment: Ooooch my bad ! Not enough focus on what I am doing..

Comment: Tried to run your circuit with a real 2N3906 without success (flat result whatever combination of R1/R2 I would try). Tried to simulate the 50kHz signal with circuitlab imgur.com/a/rcdydyh but the 2N3906 stays stuck "on". Thanks anyway @Rohat for your solution.

Comment: @JB. Sorry, but I've been using the same circuit in many circuits that I designed including an isolated 3.3V KNX transceiver, optical port for e-metering and many more and all of them run @ 19.2 kBaud. The resistance values depend on the optocoupler used but R1 = R2 = 1k could be a start for testing. Please test your connections and components.

Comment: @JB. see the edited schematic. I put a current-controlled current source to simulate the optocoupler. Please run the simulation and see the results. Remember that the resistor values depend on the optocoupler because the R1 and the parasitic capacitance form an RC filter.

Comment: Oh I got it, your circuit works ok. My input signal is the bizarre 50kHz signal in the yellow capture above. (With 9kbits/s encoded with a buzzing at 50kHz for a 0, almost not buzzing for a 1 ; and extra artefacts due to line noise) = Not a perfect 9kBaud input square. Hence my question.